# How to wait for all promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have two api call.
I want to do some calculation based on the results of both api.
I am using Promise.all() for waiting for both promises to resolve.

```js
const getHashTagList = async () => {
    loader.start();
    try {
      await getAllHashTags().then((response: any) => {
        setHashtagList([...response?.data]);
      });
    } catch (err) {
    } finally {
      loader.stop();
    }
  };
  
  
 const getUserFollowingHT = async () => {
    loader.start();
    try {
      await getUserDetails().then((response: any) => {
        setUserFollowingHT([...response?.data?.followingHashtags]);
      });
    } catch (err) {
    } finally {
      loader.stop();
    }
  };
```

For calling these 2 promises I am using below syntax:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    //getHashTagList();
    // getUserFollowingHT();
    Promise.all([getHashTagList, getUserFollowingHT]).then(
      (combineResp) => {
        console.log(combineResp);
      }
    );
  }, []);
```

But in the output I am getting function declaration syntax.
It is not able to get call those promises.

Comment: what is in the response?

Comment: You need an array of `Promise`s and not functions. -> `Promise.all([getHashTagList(), getUserFollowingHT()])`

Comment: Use need to execute the functions:
`Promise.all([getHashTagList(), getUserFollowingHT()])`

Comment: @Andreas - Missed the first code snippet..

Comment: 0: async () => {…} 1: async () => {…} length: 2 Gives this output @AmanSharma

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const values = await Promise.all([getHashTagList, getUserFollowingHT]);
    console.log(values);
  })();
}, []);
```

Comment: 0: async () => {…}
1: async () => {…}
length: 2
Gives this output

Comment: Inside whole function body of two function is there